# Conexión ODBC no descarga decimales

Tags: odbc

Buen día! tengo distintos desarrollos que obtienen información de mi servidor todos fueron hechos utilizando windows 8 (actualizado a 10) excel 2010 y una conexión ODBC de 32 bits sin embargo con **instalaciones nuevas** **de windows 10** y **office 365** trunca los decimales por favor pueden orientarme a como resolver esta situación?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Les comento que he dado con la solución resulta que como muchos programas el **iSeries** actualiza sus versiones y se solucionó instalando el service pack disponible para la versión en cuestión (V7R1 en mi caso) mismo que descargué del portal de IBM adicionalmente hay que instalar un pack de seguridad (referido en la misma pagina).